# What does "batch_all_reduce" mean in tensorflow keras model.fit output?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I saw the following message on tensorflow keras model.fit output. The model uses MirroredStrategy for distributed processing with 2 GPUs. Can someone explain what the below message mean?
[image]

Comment: Seems like it uses NVIDIA NCCL to do the work: https://developer.nvidia.com/nccl

Comment: Thanks. What does "batch_all_reduce: 8" mean?

Answer (score 1):

`batch_all_reduce` means executing all-reduce operations every training step(batch).

[All-reduce](https://tech.preferred.jp/en/blog/technologies-behind-distributed-deep-learning-allreduce/) is a mechanism for parameter synchronization between multiple devices(GPUs) in distributed training.

And according to the source code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/distribute/cross_device_ops.py#L700), 8 means the count of `dense values` in the model. These dense values then will be packed and used for parameter updating through all-reduce.